# Disable panning in UWP scrollviewer with single finger

Tags: uwp, scrollview

I want to disable panning of UWP scrollviewer with single finger. Instead i want to pan with two finger.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can use `PanningMode="VerticalOnly"` in wpf.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable panning of UWP scrollviewer with single finger, you should be able to set `HorizontalScrollMode` and `VerticalScrollMode` of the `ScrollViewer` to `Disabled`. It can not be scrolled when you use two finger.

You should be able to detect the number of fingers on the `ScrollViewer`. If there is one finger, we can set the `HorizontalScrollMode` and `VerticalScrollMode` of the `ScrollViewer` to `Disabled`. If there are 2 fingers, we can set the `HorizontalScrollMode` and `VerticalScrollMode` of the `ScrollViewer` to `Enable`.

To detect the number of fingers on the ScrollViewer, we shoule be able to listen for pointer events. There is a [Complete example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150606.aspx#complete_example) to listen the pointer events.

For example:

```html
<ScrollViewer Name="MyScrollViewer"  HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"  
              VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" 
              PointerCaptureLost="MyScrollViewer_PointerCaptureLost" PointerExited="MyScrollViewer_PointerExited"
              PointerEntered="MyScrollViewer_PointerEntered">
    <StackPanel>
        <Rectangle Width="800" Height="800" Fill="Red"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Width="800" Height="800" Fill="Beige"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Width="800" Height="800" Fill="CadetBlue"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Width="800" Height="800" Fill="DarkBlue"></Rectangle>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The code behind:

```cs
HashSet<uint> _pointers = new HashSet<uint>();
private void MyScrollViewer_PointerCaptureLost(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _pointers.Remove(GetPoint(e));
}

private void MyScrollViewer_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _pointers.Remove(GetPoint(e));
}

private void MyScrollViewer_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _pointers.Add(GetPoint(e));
    Debug.WriteLine("Count of points is" + _pointers.Count);
    if (_pointers.Count>=2)
    {
        MyScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
        MyScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
    }
    else
    {
        MyScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
        MyScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
    }
}
uint GetPoint(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    return e.GetCurrentPoint(MyScrollViewer).PointerId;
}
```